# My code is showing wrong output for a test case of leetcode

Tags: c++, c++11, vector

Question:- https://leetcode.com/problems/intersection-of-two-arrays/

This is my code:-

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<int> intersection(vector<int>& nums1, vector<int>& nums2) {
        vector <int> result;
        for(int i=0;i<nums1.size(); i++){
            for(int j=0;j<nums2.size();j++){
                if(nums1[i] == nums2[j]){
                    result.push_back(nums1[i]);
                    break;
                }   
            }
        }
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++){
            for(int j=0;j<result.size();j++){
                if(result[i] == result[j] and i!=j){
                    result.pop_back();
                }
            }
        }
        return result;
    }
};
```

I am getting wrong output for this testcase:-
Input:-

```
nums1 = [61,24,20,58,95,53,17,32,45,85,70,20,83,62,35,89,5,95,12,86,58,77,30,64,46,13,5,92,67,40,20,38,31,18,89,85,7,30,67,34,62,35,47,98,3,41,53,26,66,40,54,44,57,46,70,60,4,63,82,42,65,59,17,98,29,72,1,96,82,66,98,6,92,31,43,81,88,60,10,55,66,82,0,79,11,81]

nums2 =[5,25,4,39,57,49,93,79,7,8,49,89,2,7,73,88,45,15,34,92,84,38,85,34,16,6,99,0,2,36,68,52,73,50,77,44,61,48]
```

Expected Output:-

```
[61,45,85,89,5,77,92,38,7,34,44,57,4,6,88,0,79]
```

My Output:-

```
[61,45,85,89,5,77,5,92,38,89,85,7,34,44,57]
```

Please tell where I am getting wrong

Comment: Please provide a [mre] without relying on external links. What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Why is it a class? Why does it look like a c# code?

Comment: Anyway, the problem is this `result.pop_back();`. `pop_back()` pops out the last element. You should use something like `erase()`. Reference- https://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/erase/

Comment: @AbdurRakib because that's how solutions are formulated on leetcode?

Comment: Besides, note that your algorithm is not efficient: O(n^2). For example, you could first sort both arrays. Or use `std::set`. Using [std::set_intersection](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/set_intersection) might be useful too.

Comment: @bipill, what? I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: @AbdurRakib leetcode adds a main function which does something like `Solution a; auto res = a.intersection(num1, num2);`. e.g., it expects a memberfunction `intersection` in the class `Solution`.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the error here. The problem here is caused by inappropriate use of functions.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the 2nd loop. You try to eliminate double elements, to get a unique result.

But, after having found a duplicate, you do not erase the duplicate, but use `pop_back` which deletes the last element of the `vector` that has nothing to do with the duplicate. This, you need to correct. But, be careful, then your loops would not work anymore.

So, best is to use a different approach. You could use the function `std::set_intersection` for that. Here you must sort theinput vectors at the beginning.

Also `std::unique` is available, also requires sorting.

And you could add you result elements to a container that can only hold unique values. Like a `std::unordered_set` and then later copy back the result to the vector.

Eaxmaple for `set_intersetction`:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<int> nums1{ 61,24,20,58,95,53,17,32,45,85,70,20,83,62,35,89,5,95,12,86,58,77,30,64,46,13,5,92,67,40,20,38,31,18,89,85,7,30,67,34,62,35,47,98,3,41,53,26,66,40,54,44,57,46,70,60,4,63,82,42,65,59,17,98,29,72,1,96,82,66,98,6,92,31,43,81,88,60,10,55,66,82,0,79,11,81 };
    std::vector<int> nums2{ 5,25,4,39,57,49,93,79,7,8,49,89,2,7,73,88,45,15,34,92,84,38,85,34,16,6,99,0,2,36,68,52,73,50,77,44,61,48 };
    
    std::sort(nums1.begin(), nums1.end());
    std::sort(nums2.begin(), nums2.end());
    std::vector<int> v_intersection;

    std::set_intersection(nums1.begin(), nums1.end(),nums2.begin(), nums2.end(), std::back_inserter(v_intersection));
    for (int n : v_intersection)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```

Example for `std::unordered_set`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <unordered_set>


class Solution {
public:
    std::vector<int> intersection(std::vector<int>& nums1, std::vector<int>& nums2) {
        std::unordered_set<int> result{};
        for (int i = 0; i < nums1.size(); i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < nums2.size(); j++) {
                if (nums1[i] == nums2[j]) {
                    result.insert(nums1[i]);
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        return { result.begin(),result.end() };
    }
};
int main() {
    std::vector nums1{ 61,24,20,58,95,53,17,32,45,85,70,20,83,62,35,89,5,95,12,86,58,77,30,64,46,13,5,92,67,40,20,38,31,18,89,85,7,30,67,34,62,35,47,98,3,41,53,26,66,40,54,44,57,46,70,60,4,63,82,42,65,59,17,98,29,72,1,96,82,66,98,6,92,31,43,81,88,60,10,55,66,82,0,79,11,81 };
    std::vector nums2{ 5,25,4,39,57,49,93,79,7,8,49,89,2,7,73,88,45,15,34,92,84,38,85,34,16,6,99,0,2,36,68,52,73,50,77,44,61,48 };

    std::vector result = Solution().intersection(nums1,nums2);
    
    for (const int n : result)
        std::cout << n << ' ';
}
```